# Wi-Fi dongle with RTL8188RU chipset scanning but not connecting

Tags: wifi, driver

I obtained a ALFA AWUS036NHR with a Realtek RTL8188RU chipset Wi-Fi dongle and I am trying to get it to work on a Raspberry Pi. The device is detected correctly:

```
root@rpi1:~# lsusb | grep WLAN
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:817f Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188RU 802.11n WLAN Adapter
```

I edited `wpa_supplicant.conf` according to the [manual](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md) and then tried to bring up the connection with `sudo ifup wlan0` but failed. I looked into `/var/log/syslog` and saw the following:

```
Jul 17 15:19:31 rpi1 wpa_supplicant[1728]: wlan0: Association request to the driver failed
Jul 17 15:19:33 rpi1 wpa_supplicant[1728]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=9c:80:df:2c:8b:0a reason=0
```

Seems to be a driver problem. I found a filed [issue](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/474) concerning my case, which is still opened since December 2013. In a referenced pull request there is a message saying "3.19 is no longer updated by us. I've cherry-picked into 4.0 tree." So I updated kernel to latest version using `rpi-update`, but the issue wasn't resolved. From this point I don't know how to move on and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried specifying a different driver (e.g. *wext*) to wpa_supplicant?

First kill your old process:

```
# pkill wpa_s
```

Restart with new driver:

```
# wpa_supplicant -B -Dwext -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/your_conf.conf
```

Start dhcpcd, probably:
(maybe kill it first: `# pkill dhcpcd` )

```
# dhcpcd wlan0
```

Answer (score 0):

The below command is weird but you can try it. Afterwards, the dongle should get connected to the internet and work as supposed.

```
$ sudo apt update &&
    sudo apt install network-manager network-manager-gnome openvpn-systemd-resolved \
                     openvpn network-manager-openvpn network-manager-openvpn-gnome -y &&
      sudo apt purge openresolv dhcpcd5 -y &&
        sudo ln -sf /lib/systemd/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf && reboot
```